# Instance attribute unexpectedly loaded

Tags: python

I learned Python last year, and was just getting back into it with a new project. I've hit a snag right at the beginning, and after a bunch of poring through documentation I'm still stumped. I have to believe it's something simple, but I can't find it. Here's the issue:

I have the following set up in a file:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, title=None):
        self.header = Thing("HEADER")
        if title is not None:
            self.header.content.append( Thing("TITLE", content=[str(title)]) )
        self.body = Thing("BODY")
        self.content = Thing("COMPLETE", content=[self.header, self.body])

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, content=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
```

Then from an interactive prompt I do:

```
>>> import things
>>> a = things.Wrapper("This is a title")
```

Now, I would expect at this point that the `body` attribute of `a` would be a `Thing` instance with the name `"BODY"` and a `content` consisting of an empty list. What I'm surprised to find is that its `content` is actually a list containing the same `"TITLE"` instance that `a.header.content` holds.

```
>>> a.header.name
'HEADER'
>>> a.header.content
[<test.Thing object at 0xb752290c>]
>>> a.body.name
'BODY'
>>> a.body.content
[<test.Thing object at 0xb752290c>]
>>> a.body.content[0].name
'TITLE'
>>> a.body.content[0].content
['This is a title']
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how `a.body.content` got assigned that way. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please view this answer / explanation: ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, content=None):
        if content is None:
            content = []
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
```

The issue with [] as a default is that the default parameters are only evaluated once, when the interpreter first creates the function.  For an `int` or other *immutable* type this is fine, but for *mutable* types (lists, dictionaries, anything that can be changed in place) this causes problems.  What winds up happening is that all instances of `Thing` share the same `content`.

This way, the empty list is created **each** time you call the constructor, creating a new list every time.

Comment: That works... but why did the original fail?

Comment: see edit.  It's a bit complicated until you understand mutability

Comment: Got it. And g.d.d.c added a nice link above. Thanks!